# How to check user online with django and GAE?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm using Django with Google App Engine and I want to build a module for checking online/offline user .
But GAE don't support session so it's hard for me to find way to do it.
how can i resolve this problem? Any ideas would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A session library won't solve this, because HTTP is stateless. Using sessions, you can determine when someone last made a request, but that doesn't tell you if they're "online" or not - they could have immediately closed their browser tab, or they could leave it open for a week.

If you really, really need to do this, you could use the [channel API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/). Alternately, you could use a session library, or log users in using the Users API, and list as 'online' anyone who's made requests in the last n minutes.